# Transition from one view controller to another with a change in colour of navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have the same navigation bar in multiple viewcontrollers. When i push from one view controller to another the colour of the view controller changes, but the transition is awful. How can I achieve smooth transition? I cant find a proper code to make this work in swift.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the transition in viewWillAppear of the view controller getting pushed on and then change it back in viewWillAppear of the the first view controller that should make the transition smoother.

If you want to get fancier you could try and put it in a UIView.animateWithDuration block and animate the changes while the navigation controller is animating the transitions.